# YUV to RGB conversion and display using opengl es 2.0 from android ndk using shaders

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am currently working on a rtsp player on android using ffmpeg to connect and decode the video stream. I would like to use OpenGL es 2.0 to convert the YUV frame to RGB frame and display it but i am blocked (it's the first time i use opengl).

I will try to explain clearly what is my problem.

From the NDK android i initialize an opengl context (from the thread i want to use to display images) using this method :

```
    //
EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
};
EGLint contextAttrs[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
        EGL_NONE
};

LOGI("Initializing context");

if((display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)) == EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

if(!eglInitialize(display, 0, 0))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

if(!eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

if(!eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, 0, 0, format);

if(!(surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, window, 0)))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

if(!(context = eglCreateContext(display, config, 0, contextAttrs)))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

if(!eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

if(!eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &width) || !eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &height))
{
    closeContext();
    return;
}

LOGI("EGLWIDTH : %d EGLHEIGHT : %d ", (int)width, (int)height);

isInitEGLContext = 1;
```

Then i setup the graphics using this method :

```
    //
//Load Vertex and Fragment Shader, attach shader and link program
 programId = createProgram(kVertexShader, kFragmentShader);
 LOGI("Program id : %d error :  %d",(int) programId, glGetError());


if(!programId)
{
    LOGI("Could not create program");
    return;
}
// get index of the generic vertex attribute bound to vPosition
positionObject = (int) glGetAttribLocation(programId, "vPosition");

 // get index of the generic vertex attribute bound to vTexCoord
texturePosition = (int) glGetAttribLocation(programId, "vTexCoord");

// get the location of yTexture within the program (corresponding to   program id)
yuv_texture_object[0] = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "yTexture");

// get the location of uTexture within the program
yuv_texture_object[1] = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "uTexture");

// get the location of vTexture within the program
yuv_texture_object[2] = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "vTexture");

// Setup width of each planes (display size)
stream_yuv_width[0] = 800;
stream_yuv_width[1] = 400;
stream_yuv_width[2] = 400;

// Setup height of each planes (display size)
stream_yuv_height[0] = 600;
stream_yuv_height[1] = 300;
stream_yuv_height[2] = 300;

//set the view port
glViewport(0,0,stream_yuv_width[0],stream_yuv_height[0]);
LOGI("glViewPort() %d ", glGetError());
```

I have hardcoded the display size (for now) until i get something that work.

The createProgram method, load the shaders, create the program, compile and link the shaders successfully.

Here are my shaders :

```
const char kVertexShader[] =
"attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
"attribute vec2 vTexCoord;\n"
"varying vec2 v_vTexCoord;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"gl_Position = vPosition;\n"
"v_vTexCoord = vTexCoord;\n"
"}\n";

const char kFragmentShader[] =
"precision mediump float; \n"
"varying vec2 v_vTexCoord;\n"
"uniform sampler2D yTexture;\n"
"uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n"
"uniform sampler2D vTexture;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"float nx, ny; \n"
"nx = v_vTexCoord.x; \n"
"ny = v_vTexCoord.y; \n"
"float y=texture2D(yTexture, v_vTexCoord).r;\n"
"float u=texture2D(uTexture, vec2(nx / 2.0, ny / 2.0)).r;\n"
"float v=texture2D(vTexture, vec2(nx / 2.0, ny / 2.0)).r;\n"
"y = 1.1643 * (y - 0.0625);\n"
"u = u - 0.5; \n"
"v = v - 0.5; \n"
"float r=y + 1.5958 * v;\n"
"float g=y - 0.39173 * u - 0.81290 * v;\n"
"float b=y + 2.017 * u;\n"
"gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";

const GLfloat kVertexInformation[] = {
    -1.0f, 1.0f,           // TexCoord 0 top left
    -1.0f,-1.0f,           // TexCoord 1 bottom left
    1.0f,-1.0f,           // TexCoord 2 bottom right
    1.0f, 1.0f            // TexCoord 3 top right
};
const GLshort kTextureCoordinateInformation[] = {
    0, 0,         // TexCoord 0 top left
    0, 1,         // TexCoord 1 bottom left
    1, 1,         // TexCoord 2 bottom right
    1, 0          // TexCoord 3 top right  
};
const GLuint kStride = 0;//COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
const GLshort kIndicesInformation[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3
};
```

Then i setup the yuv textures and the render to textures, at this moment yuv_width[i] and yuv_height[i] are set to correct value:

```
void setupYUVTexture()
{
//Setup the pixel alignement
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
LOGI("glPixelStorei() : %d ", glGetError());
int i = 0;

for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
{
    //Check if the texture already setup
    if(yuv_texture_id[i] != 0)
    {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &yuv_texture_id[i]);
        yuv_texture_id[i] = 0;
    }
    // Active the i texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);

    //Generate the texture name
    glGenTextures(1, &yuv_texture_id[i]);

    // Bind the texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, yuv_texture_id[i]);

   // Setup the texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);   
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


    //Define the texture image
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, yuv_width[i], yuv_height[i], 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    LOGI("glTexImage2D() %d ", glGetError());
}
}

void renderToTexture()
{
 // Generate framebuffer object name
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufferObject);
    //Bind the framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObject);


    //Generate render buffer object name
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBufferObject);

    //Bind render buffer
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferObject);

   //Create and initialize render buffer for display RGBA with the same size of the viewport
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, 800, 600);

    //Attach render buffer to frame buffer object
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferObject);

    //Attach y plane to frame buffer object
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, yuv_texture_id[0], 0);

   //Attach u plane to frame buffer object
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, yuv_texture_id[1], 0);

     //Attach v plane to frame buffer object
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, yuv_texture_id[2], 0);

    // Bind the framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    //Check if the framebuffer is correctly setup
    GLint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        LOGI(" FBO setting fault : %d ", status);
        return;
    }
}
```

To finish, my draw frame method :

```
void drawFrame()
{
LOGI("DrawFrame");
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObject);
printGLError("glBindFramebuffer");
glUseProgram(programId);
printGLError("glUseProgram");
int i = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    printGLError("glActiveTexture");

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, yuv_texture_object[i]);
    printGLError("glBindTexture");

    glUniform1i(yuv_texture_object[i], i);
    printGLError("glUniform1i");            
    LOGI("Plan : %d Largeur : %d Hauteur : %d ", i, yuv_width[i], yuv_height[i]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,yuv_width[i], yuv_height[i], GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yuv_planes[i]);
            printGLError("glTexSubImage2D");

    }

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionObject, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, kStride, kVertexInformation);
    printGLError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    glVertexAttribPointer(texturePosition, 2, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, kStride, kTextureCoordinateInformation);
    printGLError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionObject);      
    printGLError("glVertexAttribArray");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texturePosition);
    printGLError("glVertexAttribArray");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    printGLError("glBindFramebuffer");

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, kIndicesInformation);
    printGLError("glDrawElements");

    eglSwapBuffers(display, surface);
    printGLError("eglSwapBuffers");

}
```

I initialize once the opengl textures and other attributes which are necessary, then when a frame is decode i recopy y buffer into `yuv_planes[0]`, u buffer in `yuv_planes[ 1]` and v buffer in `yuv_planes[2]`.

Once a frame is correctly decoded using ffmpeg i call in this order :
- `initContext()`
- `setupGraphics()`
- `setupYUVTexture()`
- `renderToTexture()`

then i call `drawFrame`. Of course, when everything is initialize i call directly drawFrame after each decoded frame.

There is the output i have now.

[image: Video display by opengl]

The size of the image is correct, but now i am block here. I don't understand why the image display is green !
Any ideas

Comment: Does the glTexSubImage2D report error on each of the 3 calls? Note you are using (++i) which then ranges [1, 3] instead in [0, 2]. yuv_width[3] does not seem to be defined so the last call should most definitely be wrong (for i=3). Also you should know that glGetError returns the top value from the error stack and pops it. What that means is you generally need a while loop to get all the errors from the stack. Since you do not do that you may get the error reported on the next glGetError call although it was generated by a previous line.

Comment: As I look at the shader it does not seem you are using color components as YUV but rather as RGB and then transform them to RGB. This seems ok to me but you should then use GL_RGB instead of GL_LUMINANCE and treat the RGB values in the shader as YUV which you already seem to be doing (or not, the fragment shader seems a bit strange. Maybe some comments in the code would help).

Comment: I edited the post to add comments and add the output of my Android Monitor.

To begin, glTexSubImage2D report error on the first call, and on the last call. The increment before statement i use in my for loop is correct. In this case, it will no start from 1 to 3 but 0 to 2. Some compiles use a temporary attribute if you use increment after statement, i have gotten use to write for loop this way because it will not use a temporary attribute (it's a little bit faster). I had a log before i get my Android Monitor output to show you that it's correct.

Comment: During my research, i understand the "problem" with glGetError() so i had a log after each gl call to be sure of which line goes wrong. I thought it was sufficient, i will had a while loop to see if it the error came from an other line. 
I tried using GL_RGB instead of GL_LUMINANCE, but i get the same result. I thought GL_LUMINANCE was the good "type" because i upload each planes in 3 different textures, am I wrong ? 
Is it possible that it comes from the input image size ? (no power of two), i read somewhere that it's no more an obligation in opengles 2.0 to use power of two texture.

Comment: I tried to force the input size to a power of two (by adding padding to each planes to add a correct size) to check if it was the reason but that did not work either.

Comment: What about the log from setupYUVTexture? Is it even called? I tried just a simple test which is creating a luminance texture and attach it to the frame buffer and the result status was "unsupported" GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED 0x8CDD.

Comment: I edit my post to add more information. I did a method to display opengl error correctly, and now it display any error message. I give you the detail of the call order, and of course setupYUVTexture is call. Now it display nothing and i haven't any error code, the only weird log is "new_window_surface return 0x3000"

Comment: On the java side, i don't use the glSurfaceView, but i pass the surface to the jni to use the reference in initContext() in the method eglCreateWindowSurface(), is it possible that the probleme came from this ? 
And i am sorry but in my side i don't have any GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED  for using GL_LUMINANCE .. I don't understand why it seems to work on my device and it doesn't on yours.

Comment: Not sure where the error is, but when U and V are 0, the color is green. So either you have a math error with U and V, or the actual input values for U and V are 0.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are halving the chrominance coordinates. Shouldn't they be the same as that for chrominance? They all range from 0...1, right? And personally, I would use GL_LINEAR instead of GL_NEAREST to get interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of code to go through and a lot of things that can go wrong ;). To debug these kind of issues, I would go step by step.

1. just output red (`gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)`) to make sure your configuration is working properly.
2. try to output every texture in grayscale. (`gl_FragColor = vec4(y, y, y, 1.0)`)
3. If all that is working then it most likely means your yuv => rgb conversion is wrong somewhere.
4. If that's not working, then I would suspect something in the texture mapping. Double check your `glTexSubImage2D` call. You might need to pass a different stride or use a different coordinate system.